# Postgresql return nested set of values in stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, pgtap

I'm currently doing a test in PostgreSQL using `PGTAP`.

In order to minimize redundancy in my code I placed duplicate code inside a
function. I have functions that both returns a SETOF TEXT.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION _create_common_test(
        this_argument   varchar
    ) RETURNS SETOF TEXT AS $$
            DECLARE
               RETURN NEXT IS(this_argument, 'i_am_argument1', 'Checking Argument 1');
               MORE RETURN NEXT STATEMENTS HERE....
            END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE FUNCTION test_create_common_test_1() RETURNS SETOF TEXT AS $$
        BEGIN
            RETURN NEXT _create_common_test('i_am_argument1');
        END
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE FUNCTION test_create_common_test_2() RETURNS SETOF TEXT AS $$
        BEGIN
            RETURN NEXT _create_common_test('i_am_argument2');
        END
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

`test_create_common_test_1` and `test_create_common_test_2` calls the same function `_create_common_test()` inside their function varying only in the value passed in the argument.

As for my question, Is it possible to return the returned value of `_create_common_test()` which is a `SETOF TEXT` in the functions `test_create_common_test_1` and `test_create_common_test_2`?

I have tried using PERFORM _create_common_test('i_am_argument2'),

```
CREATE FUNCTION test_create_common_test_2() RETURNS SETOF TEXT AS $$
        BEGIN
            PERFORM _create_common_test('i_am_argument2');
        END
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

but it does not enumerate the results I had inside the _create_common_test().

Comment: `perform` discards any results. You need to use `return query _create_common_test('i_am_argument2');` in `test_create_common_test_2()`

Comment: I tried running `return query _create_common_test('i_am_argument2');` but it will only cause syntax error.

Also tried running `return next _create_common_test('i_am_argument2');` and will show this error:  returned more than one row.

Comment: Sorry that needs to be `return query select ...`

Comment: yaay! thank you very much, it did work.. :) life is easier now.. hmmn, should you answer my question so that I can accept it? ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As correctly answered by [@a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) in the comments:

```
return query select * from _create_common_test('i_am_argument2');
```